# Finding the mass of a solid bounded by two surfaces

Tags: equation-solving, homework

I have bee given the problem:

> A flying saucer has shape bounded below and above by the functions:
>
> $\qquad f(x,y) = 61/5 - 12x/5 + x^2 - 12y/5 +6xy/5 +2y^2/5$
>
> and
>
> $\qquad g(x,y) = 15 - x^2 - 6xy/5 - 2y^2/5$
>
> If the density of the saucer is  $(x,y,z) = x^2 + 3z$, find the mass.

The example we were given related a different function to a numerical value, 10, and used `Solve[... == 10, y]` to find solutions to the quadratic in terms of `y` as a function of `x`, but this isn't applicable to the situation I have, so I'm kind of stuck.

Answer (score 4):

In Mathematica I would use [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate) with [`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion). First, the [`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion):

```
region = ImplicitRegion[
    Less[
        61/5 - 12 x/5 + x^2 - 12 y/5 + 6 x y/5 + 2 y^2/5,
        z,
        15 - x^2 - 6 x y/5 - 2 y^2/5
    ],
    {x,y,z}
];
Region @ region
```

[image]

Now, for the integral:

```
Integrate[
    x^2 + 3z,
    {x, y, z} ∈ region
]
```

> 34048 π/15

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you intend to use `Solve` to find the limits of integration over the density. If you define f and g in Mathematica:

```
f[x_,y_]:=61/5 - 12 x/5+x^2-12 y/5+6 x y/5+2 y^2/5;
g[x_,y_]:=15-x^2-6 x y/5-2 y^2/5;
```

And solve them for each other:

```
Solve[f[x,y]==g[x,y],y]
```

You'll find the limits for y in terms of x. In the integral, you'll use it as `{y,(3-3x-Sqrt[23-6x-x^2])/2,(3-3x+Sqrt[23-6x-x^2])/2}`, taking note that the subtracted square root is always going to be the lower bound.

Use the determinant of y's solution to find the boundaries on x:

```
Solve[23-6x-x^2==0,x]
```

The limits on x are `{x,-3-4Sqrt[2],-3+4Sqrt[2]}`. Then use `Integrate` on the density over the enclosed volume, making sure to put the x term before the y term, since the y term depends on x:

```
Integrate[x^2+3z,{x,-3-4Sqrt[2],-3+4Sqrt[2]},{y,(3-3x-Sqrt[23-6x-x^2])/2,(3-3x+Sqrt[23-6x-x^2])/2},{z,f[x,y],g[x,y]}]
```

Which should be `34048 Pi/15`.

Mathematica can figure out this condition on its own as well:

```
Integrate[(x^2+3z) Boole[f[x,y]<z<g[x,y]],{x,-Infinity,Infinity},{y,-Infinity,Infinity},{z,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

The `Boole` term is 1 when the condition `f[x,y]<z<g[x,y]` is true and 0 otherwise, so the integral can be performed over all of space. This should get the same answer.